# import throw ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

The import is working just fine from main.py outside of the scripts directory.
but when I use import in test directory, it doesn't work.. why?

```
from scripts.helpful_scripts import *
from scripts.print_something import *

print(add(1, 2))
print_something()
```

the Code inside main.py and test_scripts.py is exactly the same, but import in test_scripts.py throw ModuleNotFoundError.

This is how the directory looks like:

```
scripts--
        |-- helpful_scripts.py
        |-- print_something.py
        |-- __init__.py

test----|
        |-- test_scripts.py
        |-- __init__.py

main.py
```

The problem is python file inside test folder doesn't recognize scripts folder as module. how to solve this?

Comment: Please, always post code as text. [Reason](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test package donot have any package or module named scripts because the scripts is one step outside from where you are trying to execute the script.
While in `main.py` the directory from where you are executing the code has the package named scripts from where you can import the modules.
You may not be able to execute while being in test package the root directory must contain the imports or the pip

Comment: I don't understand this part:
 "You may not be able to execute while being in test package the root directory must contain the imports or the pip"

Comment: I tried: sys.path.append('to/scripts/directory') in test_scripts.py and it works. Then when I tried to create another folder test_one/print_test_one.py and try using the same method in test_scripts.py, it throw error again.

Comment: The directory in which you are executing the code is the root directory. If the module or package is not in the root directory program wont be able to find it unless it is a pip module.

Comment: @NarithChesda why are you appending `to/script/directory` or I am not understanding what you wanted to say. May `import os` and get `basePath = os.getcwd()` and then get `prevDir = os.path.split(basePath)[0]` Now append this one. It may help you...

Comment: I used to work on other project, if I want to import python file from other folder, I just have to:
from folder.filename import * 
but the problem now is that folder is not recognize as module.
do you know how to solve this?